# flink log missing when processing large amount of data

Tags: apache-flink

I'm testing the performance of flink processing different amount of data, so I need the Job Runtime to record and analyse .

When I use flink to processing a small dataset like ten thousand records, I can get the Job Runtime log as below.

```
07/18/2017 17:41:47 DataSink (collect())(1/1) switched to FINISHED
07/18/2017 17:41:47 Job execution switched to status FINISHED.
Program execution finished
Job with JobID 3f7658725aaae8cd3427d2aad921f2ef has finished.
Job Runtime: 1124 ms
Accumulator Results:
- c28953fb854da74d18dc7c168b988ca2 (java.util.ArrayList) [15433 elements]
```

But when I use flink to processing a little bit larger dataset like Fifty thousand records, I can't get Job Runtime info, as below, and the shell stucked:

```
07/18/2017 17:49:33 DataSink (collect())(1/1) switched to FINISHED
07/18/2017 17:49:33 Job execution switched to status FINISHED.
```

Is there any configuration I need to modify?

Why the shell stucked when the dataset is bigger?

Hope someone can answer my doubts.Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink uses Akka for remote communication, and the accumulator results are sent as a single message back to the client.  Akka imposes a maximum message size, and you may be hitting the limit.  A few suggestions:

1. Check the JobManager log for error messages related to Akka.
2. Increase the maximum size via the Flink configuration, e.g. `akka.framesize`.   See [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html#distributed-coordination-via-akka) for more information.

Comment: I increased the akka.framesize, and the problem solved.Thank you~